# Make the width of the outer div vary according to the contents of the inner divs

Tags: css, css-float, responsive-design, fluid-layout

I am trying to display the thumbnail class in a new line incase they dont fit in the width of the outer-1 div, without showing any empty spaces in outer-1 div.

```
<div class="outer-block">
    <div class="outer-1">
        <div class="thumbnail">box 1</div>
        <div class="thumbnail">box 2</div>
        ...
        <div class="thumbnail">box 7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The size of the thumbnail class is fixed to width, height of 160px, 160px. I am trying to make  the width of outer-1 div to be a multiple of 160px so that additional divs with the thumbnail class wrap to the next line.

Also I am trying to center the contents of outer-1 div with respect to the outer-block div.

Here is the link to my jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/K2v3W/2/

Comment: Since you have a 2px border on the thumbnails, you will have to do it in multiples of 164px.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you want the outer-1 to be auto full width thus the only way to do this with just html/css is to use media query to set the width of outer-1 in multiple of 160px.

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/